# Parsing data using strtok

Tags: c, parsing, strtok

I have a line of data

```
211L    CRYST1   60.970   60.970   97.140   90.000   90.000  120.000  P 32 2 1         6
```

that I want to parse in C. Specifically I want to extract `P 32 2 1` as a single string.

When I use strtok it uses all white space as delimiters giving me back the individual strings

```
P
32
2
1
```

A more concise phrasing of the question:

If I have a variable number of strings(4 in this case), how can I concatenate them into a single string?

My code so far:

```
while (fgets(line,sizeof line, PDBlist)!=NULL)
{
    p=0;
    pch=strtok(line,"\t");
    sprintf(space[p],"%s",pch);

    while(pch!=NULL){
        pch=strtok(NULL," ");
        p++;
        sprintf(space[p],"%s",pch);

    }

for(i=8;i<(p-1);i++){

        if(i==(p-2))printf("%s\n",space[i]);
        else printf("%s ",space[i]);

        }   }*
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have so far? It will make it easier for people to assist.

Comment: Any specific constraints on the format? Or may you use as well substring(s, 143, 11)?

Comment: If the format of the input string is static `sscanf()` would be useful and can provide a level of validation (for `float`s and number of expected tokens) with little effort.

Comment: I edited the post above - hope the changes help

Answer (score 1):

If the format of the lines are always as the example posted, an alternative to using `strtok()` would be [`sscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). It provides a level of validation for the line content with no additional coding (for example, validating the `float` values):

```
const char* input = "211L    CRYST1   ....";
char first_token[32];
char second_token[32];
float float_1, float_2, float_3, float_4, float_5, float_6;
char last_token[32];

/* The '%31s' means read next sequence of non-whitespace characters
   but don't read anymore than 31. 31 is used to leave space
   for terminating NULL character.

   '%f' is for reading a float.

   '%31[^\n]' means read next sequence of characters up to newline
   but don't read anymore than 31. */
if (9 == sscanf(input, "%31s %31s %f %f %f %f %f %f %31[^\n]",
                first_token,
                second_token,
                &float_1,
                &float_2,
                &float_3,
                &float_4,
                &float_5,
                &float_6,
                last_token))
{
    /* Successfully read 9 tokens. */
}
```

See online demo at http://ideone.com/To4ZP .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!

This is the solution I've come up with:

If you have a variable number of tokens first create an array with each token:

```
while(pch!=NULL){
                pch=strtok(NULL," ");
                p++;
                sprintf(space[p],"%s ",pch);    

            }
```

extract the tokens you want and concatenate them to into a single string by first using strcpy and then using strcat

```
 for(i=8;i<(p-1);i++){


                if(i==8)strcpy(dummy,space[i]);
                else strcat(dummy,space[i]);

            }
```

Thanks again! I think I made the problem WAY more confusing in the question that it turned out to be. If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char line[128] = "211L    CRYST1   60.970   60.970   97.140   90.000   90.000  120.000  P 32 2 1         6\n";
    char field8_11[32];
    char *p, *field[13];
    int i=0;
    for(p=line;NULL!=(p=strtok(p," \t\n"));p=NULL){
        field[i++]=p;
    }
    sprintf(field8_11, "%s %s %s %s", field[8], field[9], field[10], field[11]);
    printf("%s\n", field8_11);
    return 0;
}
```